# How to write complicated function to aggregate DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation

I have a DataFrame in Python like below, which presents agreements of clients:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID"         : [1,2,1,1,3],
                   "amount"     : [100,200,300,400,500],
                   "status"     : ["active", "finished", "finished", 
                                  "active", "finished"]})
```

I need to write FUNCTION in Python, which will calculate:
1.Number (NumAg) and amount (AmAg) of contracts per "ID"
2.Number (NumAct) and amount of active (AmAct) contracts per ID
3.Number (NumFin) and amount of finished (AmFin) contracts per ID

To be more precision i need to create by this function DataFrame like below:

[image]

Comment: If it's too complex, just break it down into single lines of code.

Comment: but how ? Could you suggest something ?

Comment: For the first 2 for example: `groupby('ID').agg(NumAg = pd.NamedAgg(column='amount',aggfunc='count'),AmAg = pd.NamedAgg(column='amount',aggfunc='sum'))`

Comment: Thank you and do you have idea for point 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The below solution should fit your use case.

```py
import pandas as pd

def summarise_df(df):  
    # Define mask to filter df by 'active' value in 'status' column for 'NumAct', 'AmAct', 'NumFin', and 'AmFin' columns
    active_mask = df['status'].str.contains('active') 
    return df.groupby('ID').agg( # Create first columns in output df using agg (no mask needed) 
            NumAg=pd.NamedAgg(column='amount', aggfunc='count'),
            AmAg=pd.NamedAgg(column='amount', aggfunc='sum'
        )).join( # Add columns using values with 'active' status
        df[active_mask].groupby('ID').agg( 
            NumAct=pd.NamedAgg(column='amount', aggfunc='count'),
            AmAct=pd.NamedAgg(column='amount', aggfunc='sum')
        )).join( # Add columns using values with NOT 'active' (i.e. 'finished') status
        df[~active_mask].groupby('ID').agg( 
            NumFin=pd.NamedAgg(column='amount', aggfunc='count'),
            AmFin=pd.NamedAgg(column='amount', aggfunc='sum')
        )).fillna(0) # Replace nan values with 0
```

I would recommend reading over this function and its comments alongside documentation for [`groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) so that you can develop a better understanding of exactly what is being done here. It is seldom a wise decision to rely upon code that you don't have a good grasp on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `ID` with [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html), after adding two `bool` columns that make the aggregation easier:

```
df['AmAct'] = df.amount[df.status.eq('active')]
df['AmFin'] = df.amount[df.status.eq('finished')]
df = df.groupby('ID').agg(
        NumAg = ('ID', 'count'),
        AmAg = ('amount', 'sum'),
        NumAct = ('status', lambda col: col.eq('active').sum()),
        AmAct = ('AmAct', 'sum'),
        NumFin = ('status', lambda col: col.eq('finished').sum()),
        AmFin = ('AmFin', 'sum')
     )
```

Result:

```
    NumAg  AmAg  NumAct  AmAct  NumFin  AmFin
ID                                           
1       3   800       2  500.0       1  300.0
2       1   200       0    0.0       1  200.0
3       1   500       0    0.0       1  500.0
```

Or add some more columns to `df` to do a simpler [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `ID` with `sum`:

```
df.insert(1, 'NumAg', 1)
df['NumAct'] = df.status.eq('active')
df['AmAct'] = df.amount[df.NumAct]
df['NumFin'] = df.status.eq('finished')
df['AmFin'] = df.amount[df.NumFin]
df.drop(columns=['status'], inplace=True)
df = df.groupby('ID').sum().rename(columns={'amount': 'AmAg'})
```

with the same result.

Or, maybe the easiest way, let [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) do most of the work, after adding a `count` column to `df`, and some column-rearranging afterwards:

```
df['count'] = 1
df = df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='status', values=['count', 'amount'],
                    aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0, margins=True).drop('All')
df.columns = ['AmAct', 'AmFin', 'AmAg', 'NumAct', 'NumFin', 'NumAg']
df = df[['NumAg', 'AmAg', 'NumAct', 'AmAct', 'NumFin', 'AmFin']]
```